# What JAR files are needed for Eclipse to use JSTL so it ultimately works on GAE/J?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I've been trying for longer than I'd like to admit to get JSTL working under Eclipse (and ultimately under GAE/J).  I've downloaded Eclipse, the Google App Engine Extension for Eclipse, and JSTL (http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/ - jstl-1.2.jar is in the WEB-INF\lib directory).

My code is below along with the output:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Test Page</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
Test Page

<c:set var="myvar" value="3"/>

</BODY></HTML>
```

The error I get is:

```
The tag handler class for "c:set" (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.SetTag) was not found on the Java Build Path 
test.jsp
[my app's path and name]
line 8
JSP Problem
```

From the last post on this page I don't think I need a standard.jar (http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=701267) and in any case I couldn't find one on the Oracle download.java.com site along with the jstl jar.

EDIT 4: Works now - Steps:
1) Use the Apache version
2) Actually include the jar file in the build path (right click the eclipse project and  hit Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Class Folder...; the war/WEB-INF/lib is apparently not on the build path by default)
3) Add the file c.tld to war/WEB-INF/tld

Make your web.xml look like:

```
<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>JSTLExample</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>  
</web-app>
```

The test jsp file contents:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

 <!-- Taglib -->
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Test Apache ServiceMix with JSTL</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 This is a testpage.

 <%= "hello" %>
 <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10" step="1">
 <c:out value="${i}" />

 <br />
 </c:forEach>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: That's trange: i hade the same problem with jstl.jar and if i have downloaded from where you say it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that your `web.xml` root declaration complies *at least* Servlet 2.4.

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

Or if your servletcontainer supports it, prefer 2.5:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

O if it supports the latest version3.0

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

Otherwise everything will fall back to least supported modus and taglibs may break like that.

Also ensure that you don't have loose `tld` files wandering around in the classpath (the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, among others), they will collide with the ones in JAR files. Oh, also ensure that you didn't manually define the tlds in `web.xml`, keep it clean.

Comment: Hmm, I just get an additional error when I do this:Attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" must be declared for element type "web-app".
Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "web-app".
Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app".
Attribute "version" must be declared for element type "web-app".

Comment: Get rid of that DOCTYPE. This is Servlet 2.3 specific.

Comment: Still the same error; I created a new project (this time without support for GWT - just GAE) and the web.xml bits you suggested were automatically added but as soon as I add the line <c:set var="myvar" value="3"/> I get the same error...

Comment: Did you declare it as servlet 2.4 or 2.5? Your edit is ambiguous. Which version does the servletcontainer support? You should declare the web.xml to match the servletcontainer's maximum supported version. JSTL 1.2 is designed for Servlet 2.5, but does work on Servlet 2.4 when the servletcontainer technically supports 2.5. If the servletcontainer technically doesn't support higher than Servlet 2.4, you need to fall back to JSTL 1.1. It's available [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/site/downloads/downloads_taglibs-standard.cgi). It consists of two JAR files in lib: jstl.jar and standard.jar.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remove the old one first.  I tried with both 2.4 and 2.5 and I tried adding both to the web.xml first and then to the appengine-web.xml both with no luck.  I still get the same error and a null pointer exception if I run it.  I'm thinking of trying the Apache implementation (I think the one at java.net is Sun/Oracle's - maybe it doesn't play nice with my version of Eclipse and Google-GAE plugin).

Comment: GAE has always been an odd beast. I've never seen problems like that on normal servletcontainers.

Comment: @BalusC Can you sejavax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator at this question, coz I couldn't find any solution [javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator - at running progect under tomcat7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010309/javax-servlet-jsp-tagext-taglibraryvalidator-at-running-progect-under-tomcat7)

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue and I simply put the prefix = "c" **at the end** of the taglib definition

before:

```
<%@ taglib  prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

after:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

And all warnings disappear from Eclipse.

Comment: that can't be . any order is fine

Comment: It works for me ! Should this be a bug for Eclipse ?

Comment: After swapping the attributes once, exactly as shown, the warning disappeared for me even after reverting the items to their original positions. Definitely a bug in Eclipse or whatever's linting these files.

Comment: @cjm that's right! I had the same problem and fixed it just by changing the positions of the tags and yes, once you have changed it, both the combinations work :D

Answer (score 8):

You only need to specify this dependency in your Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In my code, this provided everything I needed for the following JSP taglib to work:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: This worked for me, (I had every other thing in place as mentioned in the answers)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you need jstl.jar and standard.jar. Put those under WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Add **taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5** from **Apache** to the build path of the project. This may resolve the issue.

Comment: Is taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5  equal to jstl.jar?

Answer (score 0):

add jstl-1.2-sources.jar into your Tomcat\lib directory

Comment: Hi, maybe you can elaborate more on your answer.