# JSP Expression Language Error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have created a dynamic web module project usig STS and Spring MVC. The problem is I have add a string into a Model but it cannot be display on the JSP page using EL.

May I know what wrong with it?

Below is the details: 
JSP Page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
    Home 
    <br />

    <c:out value="${message}" /> 

</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
```

MVC Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    public HomeController() {
        super();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showHomePage() {

        // View Name - Model Name - Model Data
        return new ModelAndView("home", "message", "Hello Spring MVC");
    }
}
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- http://www.jpalace.org/docs/tutorials/spring/mvc_10.html -->

    <!-- Context Scan -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.peter.controller"/>

    <!-- Handler Mapping -->
    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler Adapter - AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter --> 
    <!-- Invoke Handler Method -->
    <bean id="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    </bean> 

    <!-- Pre/Post Handler Interceptor -->
    <!-- 
    Implement HandlerInterceptor 
    Declare HandlerInterceptor inside DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping property or 
    globally inside <mvc:interceptors>
    Need configure Filter object inside web.xml 

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <bean class="pckg.MyInterceptor1"/>
                <bean class="pckg.MyInterceptor2"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="pckg.MyInterceptor1"/>
        <bean class="pckg.MyInterceptor2"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    -->

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Exception Resolver -->

    <!-- Register Interceptor, Message Resource, Bean validation support, Message conversion and field formatting -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

I have JSTL.jar in my build path. There is warning message about the The tag handler class for "c:out" (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag) was not found on the Java Build Path

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: your view resolver works good ? I mean are you able to see this jsp then you hit `/context/home `?

Comment: Post your spring servlet context.xml to verify your ViewResolvers and View.

Comment: Yes, The welcome page is display accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052552/what-jar-files-are-needed-for-eclipse-to-use-jstl-so-it-ultimately-works-on-gae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download jstl-1.2.jar from the maven repo   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/).
- Ensure that
  the jar is available in WEB-INF\lib folder of your web application.

Comment: I have set the JSTL.jar in the deployment assembly option.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to view your viewResolver configuration. Are you able to view the home page?? or there is 404 error?

If home.jsp is displaying properly then according to me the problem is in your jsp.
Look at the first line of the jsp where you have defined the page directive.

In that declaration remove the attribute `isELIgnored="false"` it is bydefault false everytime. So no need to define it explicitely.

I think if you remove that attribute. Your `${message}` would display correctly.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, i able to view the home page. I had removed the attribute but still does not display the message.

Comment: What are you getting in place of ${message} in your jsp when it is displayed in browser?