# Liferay MVCPortlet connect FORM actionURL with action

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm a new user on Liferay. I'm trying to connect my form on the `view.jsp`:

```java
<portlet:actionURL name="addRule" var="addRuleURL"/>
<aui:form action="<%= addRuleURL.toString() %>" method="post">
    .....
```

With the action in the `ActionUtil.java` (using Hibernate - Service Builder):

```java
@ProcessAction(name = "addRule")
public void addRule(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
```

But I can't, Eclipse says:

```java
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.addRule(javax.portlet.ActionRequest, javax.portlet.ActionResponse)
```

What can I do to connect my form in the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are having this problem because you did not include your portlet in `portlet.xml`, so Liferay eventually uses the default MVCPortlet class which does not have the `addRule` method. So make sure you have something like this in `portlet.xml` for your custom MVC portlet:

```xml
<portlet-name>yourmvcportlet</portlet-name>
<display-name>Your MVC Portlet</display-name>
<portlet-class>your.portlet.package.YourMVCPortlet</portlet-class>
<init-param>
  <name>view-jsp</name>
  <value>/jsp/view.jsp</value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I noticed that and I added this: <portlet-class>com.liferay.oriol.inputrules.model.portlet.ActionUtil</portlet-class> but this error appeared to me: The portlet class com.liferay.oriol.inputrules.model.portlet.ActionUtil was not found on the Java Build Path how can I solve it?? Thank you!

Comment: I also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795462/jsp-expression-language-error                                            ....but the error is still there.

Comment: Which development environment are you using? Liferay IDE (Eclipse + Liferay plugin)? Are you using maven?

Comment: Ok I refresh the project and loading the jar all was solved. Thank you so much